# Electronic Music

Tags: halal-haram, music

Asalamu alaykum, is electronic music (e.g. Dubstep) haram? It is mainly made using computer sounds that cannot be played by musical instruments.

Comment: Would you accept an answer to general Music or do you just want electronic Music in particular only? imo Music is not Haram, so the answer would cover both aspects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: In the name of Allah, Most Beneficent, Most Merciful]

Let me start with an example. Just because Heroin and Cocaine weren't there at the time of Prophet(pbuh), it doesn't mean it isn't covered by Shari'ah. Since they too turn the people insane just like alcohol, they are automatically condemned.

> #### [Sunan Ibn Majah 4020](http://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/36/95)
>
> **It was narrated from Abu Malik Ash’ari that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)said:**
>
> “People among my nation **will drink wine, calling it by another
> name**, and **musical instruments** will be played for them and singing
> girls (will sing for them). Allah will cause the earth to swallow them
> up, and will turn them into monkeys and pigs.”

You fail to understand the motive behind condemning musical instruments in Islam. The motive is nothing but the ***music*** alone. It is just like liquor which is banned due to its intoxicating nature.

So ultimately it doesn't matter whether the music comes from real instruments or virtual instruments (softwares). Only thing matters is the music which is *condemned (haraam)*.

> ### [Luqman (31:6)](http://quran.com/31/6)
>
> And of mankind is he who purchases idle talks (i.e.music, singing, etc.) to mislead (men) from the Path of Allah without knowledge, and takes it (the Path of Allah, the Verses of the Quran) by way of mockery. For such there will be a humiliating torment (in the Hell-fire).
>
> *Translation by Muhsin Khan*

#### ۚ  وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ (And Allah is the All-Knower, the Wise)

#### اللَّهُمَّ انْفَعْنِي بِمَا عَلَّمْـتَنِي وَ عَلِّمْنِي مَا يَنْفَعُنِي

Comment: If I follow you, listen music is prohibited? How can you say what is condemned is listening music alone and not the three actions together?

Comment: @YohannV, what makes you believe that they are haraam only if together?.... Majority of scholars interpret [this aayah](http://quran.com/31/6) to be making a mention of Music and hence consider it *haraam*.

Comment: Isn't it only talking about the speech? Or does it have the meaning of *every sound that go out our mouth*? At this point, the only thing I understand is that drink alcohol with music and girls singing is prohibited as much as using speech to mislead people about the Path of Allah. How can music that celebrates the greatness of Allah be haram?

Comment: @YohannV. Please go through [**this answer by Sheikh Al-Munajjid**](http://islamqa.info/en/5000) for a scholarly opinion on the issue you have raised.